# Iterate over large collection in django - cache problem

Tags: python, django-models

I need to iterate over large collection (3 * 10^6 elements) in Django to do some kind of analysis that can't be done using single SQL statement.

- Is it possible to turn off collection caching in django? (Caching all the data is not to be acceptable data has around 0.5GB)
- Is it possible to make django fetch collection in chunks? It seems that it tries to pre fetch whole collection in to the memory and then iterate over it. I think that observing the speed of execution:

  - `iter(Coll.objects.all()).next()` - this takes forever
  - `iter(Coll.objects.all()[:10000]).next()` - this takes less than a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`QuerySet.iterator()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.iterator) to walk over the results instead of loading them all first.

Comment: But it doesn't seams to work. But It could be a bug in django.

Comment: I'm using sqlite and according to source code it doesn't support reads in chunks. :(

Comment: Well then I guess you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that the problem was caused by the database backend (sqlite) that doesn't support reading in chunks. 
I've used sqlite as the database will be trashed after I do all the computations but it seems that sqlite isn't good even for that.

Here is what I've found in django source code of sqlite backend:

```
class DatabaseFeatures(BaseDatabaseFeatures):
    # SQLite cannot handle us only partially reading from a cursor's result set
    # and then writing the same rows to the database in another cursor. This
    # setting ensures we always read result sets fully into memory all in one
    # go.
    can_use_chunked_reads = False
```